# TeamWin “No OS Installed” Android Nexus 5

Tags: rooting, root-access, twrp, unrooting, operating-system

I lost my phone in Peru and had to downgrade to my old Nexus 5. It was rooted so I couldn't update the OS. In trying to unroot it, I [somehow] deleted the OS, and now the phone won't boot. I get to the TeamWin recovery options and it will say "No OS Installed, are you sure you want to..." How can I fix this?

Note: nexus 5 does not allow for external SDs to transfer files, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! No complete instructions (I have no N5), but the basic answer is: download a ROM for it, and flash that ROM. To get you started on the topic, please check with our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reflash the stock Google Factory Firmware image for your device with fastboot.

Instructions and images are available [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images). Make sure to use a quality USB cable... we have had several bricking issues flashing firmware on Nexus 5 devices because of defective or poor quality USB cables.